# javascript to play audio tag

Tags: javascript, audio

i have audio swf file.
i am playing it with object tag, but the problem is that it is not looping.

here is the html:

```html
<object height="0" data="audioo.swf">
        <param name="autostart" value="true" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
        <param name="Loop" value="True" />
        <audio id="audi" src="audioo.swf" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
            <source src="audioo.swf" type="audio/swf" />
        </audio>
    </object>
```

so i try to use javascript to make the file loop every some time but no any effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bc;
    function hh()
    {
        bc = setInterval(abcd, 17000);
    }
    function abcd()
    {
        document.getElementById("audi").play();
    }
</script>
```

please if any help
thank you very much

Comment: Are you calling `hh()` function anywhere?

Comment: I note that your first parameters (`autostart` and `autoplay`) along with their values are all lowercase, while your `Loop` one and its value is not.  Might the swf be case sensitive?

Comment: Do you want to play audio in loop ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("audi")`. There is no element with ID `audi`. Also, I don't think any of this is going to work anyway. `<audio>` can't play SWF files

Comment: thank you @RGraham ID audi is for audio tag. i forget to put it in my question

Comment: thank you @MarcosPérezGude i am not calling hh() anywhere in body

Comment: thank you @ManishaSrivastava yes i only want to loop the swf file

Comment: You should call hh() function when dom is ready, better at the end of the body tag

Comment: thank you @JamesThorpe i try it before to write loop but it still not works

Comment: thank you @MarcosPérezGude i am writing javascript in the head tag. i need the file to loop automatically as it is playing as the page load. please if you can help me

Comment: @RGraham audio tag is playing the swf file as the page load but the problem is not looping

Comment: I don't think it is. Your `<object>` tag is probably playing the swf

Comment: Do you need the `<object>` tag? is better if you use `<audio>` tag only to play it, but I don't know if you have another source.

Comment: Ok , in that case you can use HTML 5 Audio tag, and do test it before run that does html 5 audio tag is  supported  by your browser or not.

Comment: @RGraham you are properly right. i think it is object tag. but also object tag is not looping the swf file

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude audio tag alone is not playing swf file

Comment: @ManishaSrivastava thank you. i am using audio tag and object tag to support all browsers. the file is playing. but the problem is that it is not looping after finishing the first time

Comment: thank you @RGraham for help. Please if you can tell me where i have to call the hh() function. my javascript is in head tag and i am not calling any thing in the body html

Comment: Ok I could see you are not using this tag <audio controls loop> try this..

Comment: Audio tag don't play swf files. convert it to mp3 / ogg and you solve all the problems caused by object tag

Comment: @ManishaSrivastava thank you very much. i am using xhtml and this tag is not supported. when i try it it is underlined red

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude. i try mp3 file with audio tag. it is never playing. whereas swf file with embed tag or object tag is playing but not loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<audio controls loop>
  <source src="voice.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="auido.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: thank you. i try this code before but it not works. the audio tag without object tag is not playing the swf file

Comment: Ok. I guess there is also problem with swf file , have you tried some other format ? try to use mp3 and see if it works ..

Comment: thanks Manisha Srivastava . Yes, i before try mp3 and wav file, but they are not playing.

Comment: swf is playing but i need to loop after end.